# Is there any way to check if "never type" and raise error or warning for it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

If a variable is never without intension, in my opinion, it'd better to raise error by linter.

In the case like below.

```
const nameVariable = "Bob";

const result = `Mr. ${name}` // >> I wanna get error for this line.
```

Comment: On browsers, `window.name` is defined, so that (unfortunately) will compile and run. Change it to most anything else and `no-undef` should throw, I think. Wonder why it's typed as `never` though (I can reproduce that too), I'd have thought it'd be a string... `declare const name: never;` on 19558 of `lib.dom.d.ts`, weird

Comment: @CertainPerformance Why `never`? -> [Improve type safety of `name` global variable #15424](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15424)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks your replay. I didn't know that, interesting.
So this is special problem the variable named 'name'.